# Is there a powershell script which will put a Windows device to sleep for sometime and wake it up automatically?

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a powershell script which will put a Windows device to sleep for sometime and wake it up automatically?

Most scripts are working for desktops but not for laptops when they are on battery power as well as on charge.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is able to achieve your desired actions:

```
# Get the wake-up time from user input
$wakeUpTime = Read-Host "Enter the wake-up time in 24-hour format (e.g. 19:13)"

# Convert wake-up time to a DateTime object
$wakeUpDateTime = Get-Date $wakeUpTime

# Calculate the number of seconds until the wake-up time
$secondsUntilWakeUp = ($wakeUpDateTime - (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds

# Register a wake-up task
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute cmd -Argument '/c start /min "" powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command {$myshell=New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell" $myshell.sendkeys(" ")}'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $wakeUpDateTime
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -WakeToRun
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "WakeUpTask" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -settings $settings -User "SYSTEM"

# Put device to sleep
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState('Suspend', $false, $false)

# Wait until it's time to wake up
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# Delete the wake-up task
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "WakeUpTask" -Confirm:$false
```